# Background for all iOS listviews

Tags: kendo-mobile

I have been trying to change the background color to all the listview elements in my Kendo-ui mobile application without any luck, I have tried:

```
.km-list>li {
    background: transparent;
}
```

---

```
.km-root .km-ios .km-list>li {
    background: transparent;
}
```

---

```
.km-root .km-ios .km-content .km-list>li {
    background: transparent;
}
```

I will appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Kendo UI Mobile ThemeBuilder](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobilethemebuilder/index.html), it may help.